# "./setup.sh: Permission denied" error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I came across this problem that I am not sure where it's pointing. I have tried looking various sample codes but nothing that matches my problem. If anyone can look into it I will appreciate. The error is:

> /Users/TMK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-dfuciscypawvmsalewmxognechca/Build/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mustage.build/Script-01D7EAEB1DA69C8000FF7607.sh: line 3: ./setup.sh: Permission denied

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder (Option+Shift+Command+K), restarting Xcode and try it again. It seems like you have a permission issue for something that might just be due to a change that the build folder can't resolve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is seems like permission issue towards user.
When you trying to work with modified projects and scripts no neccessory of **bin/sh** any more.

Following are the steps to avoid this error.

- Terminal
- Go to your script
- Run the command `chmod 755 your_script_name.sh`

Another Way is as below

Suppose `myTODO` is my project name

Try this `chmod a+x "/Users/TMK/Desktop/Your_FolderName/oDesk/myTODO/MyTODO_iPho‌​ne/Pods/Pods-resourc‌​es.sh"`

*if you not containing some folder hierarchy please avoid it from the given path*

Hope this help you

Comment: I tried doing that but still nothing. Even after running the command on the terminal it is not doing anything.